# HTML5 Drag & Drop create copy of original in target?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Hey I have searched and can't find an answer to my question that I can get to work...

Basically what I am trying to create is a 'basket' type thing on a site to drop 'products' into, that is simple enough however when using default drag and drop it simple moves the original product (will be an image) to the drop zone, I want the product to be copied instead so that however many times you drop it into the basket it will always still be visible and drag-able in the original position.
I have been playing around using this example... http://jsfiddle.net/WpWBG/1/ i thought i could just add `e.dataTransfer.dropEffect='copy';` and `e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='copy';` to the drag_start function but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Thanks
Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of scenario, I would recommend using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Take a look at the [shopping cart demo](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart) for example, it does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response I will take a look at this tomorrow when I get a spare minute! Hopefully this will be the solution, glancing at it, it seems to do what I need so fingers crossed!